# sendGTMEvent for Next.js does not submit to Google Analytics

Tags: next.js, google-analytics

I'm trying to learn how to submit a custom event to Google Analytics from a Next.js project.  This documentation says I should use `sendGTMEvent`:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/third-party-libraries

When I use `sendGTMEvent`, it adds an item do the `dataLayer`, but nothing actually gets transmitted to Google Analytics. And I don't see any mention of my custom event in Google Analytics.  This is the code I have:

```
/// app/layout.tsx
import GoogleAnalytics from './GoogleAnalytics'

export default async function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <GoogleAnalytics />
        <main className="">{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

```
/// app/GoogleAnalytics.tsx
'use client'

import { GoogleTagManager } from '@next/third-parties/google'

const gtmId : string = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ID ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_ID : ""

function GA() {

  return <GoogleTagManager gtmId={gtmId} />
}

export default GA
```

```
/// app/Form.tsx
'use client'

import { sendGTMEvent } from '@next/third-parties/google'


export default function Form() {
setInterval(() => {
  if( typeof window === "undefined" ) {
    return null
  }
    dataLayer.push({'event':'MyTest1','conversionValue':25});
    sendGTMEvent({ event: 'MyTest2', value: 'hello-world' })
    console.log('submitting' )
}, 3000);

  return <div>Hello World</div>
}
```

When I visit my browser at `http://localhost:3000`, I see the word `Hello World`, which means my website loaded properly.  When I open up `Chrome Developer Tools>Console`, I see that every 3 seconds, the word `submitting` is visible.  I can see that the `dataLayer` array is growing in length as more records are added to it.

But I don't see any attempts by my javascript to send data to Google.  The `Chrome Developer Tools>Network` tab show zero attempts to submit anything to Google besides the initial page load.

I tried reading documentation and blogs on the subject, but it's not clear to me what function I am supposed to call to actually "send information" to GA?

---

Additional Notes:

When I visit Google Analytics and look at Real Time Dashboards, I do not see any mention of `MyTest1` or `MyTest2` in this widget here:

[image]

I tried clicking into each row to drill down further, but couldn't find any mention of `MyTest1` or `MyTest2`

Comment: If you figured this out, I would appreciate an answer post!

Comment: @AndrewK - I never got things to work. So instead, I cheated and build a JS module then imported it into my TypeScript module using the approach in this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77742605/unable-to-send-custom-variable-value-event-to-ga4

Comment: Thanks. I have been working on this for 5 hours with no resolution, so I will do the same.

Answer (score 2):

First of all. dataLayer is just an array. It doesn't do anything on it's own. You need something to listen to its push method. Quite a few libraries do that. In particular, GTM. Therefore, when you debug, and you see changes in the array but no network requests, it's a telltale sign of GTM issues, so your next debugging step is to inspect GTM's internal logic.

From Next's or any other front-end framework's perspective, it does all properly. dataLayer is where the responsibility of the typical front-end ends and the world of analytics begins. So the problem is most definitely not in Next unless it doesn't load the GTM library, but you'd notice that, so it should be ok.

GTM is a large suite that will load gtag.js or many other libraries automatically and completely transparently to the front-end as needed. The caveat is that someone would have to go and set up the logic for events through GTM's UI. It's not a big deal, but it will certainly take some time. Read more about GTM [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/13034206?hl=en).

Most likely, you just lack GTM set up. You should go there, making sure the GTM suite you go to has the correct id. Whatever you have in your `gtmId` const. Or just open Elements and see the id in the dom script snippet, it should have the code that looks like GTM-XXXXXX. Ok, once you're there, make sure it doesn't have existing analytics logic and if it's indeed an empty container then:

1. Make a tag of Google Tag type. Have your GA4 measurement id there as `Tag ID` so that it would send the event to the correct GA4 property. Set a page load trigger there. "All Pages" of the "Page View" type. This will effectively load the gtag library attuned to your GA4 property on every page.
2. Make a trigger of type Data Layer Event (DLE), and in the trigger have `MyTest1` as a name.
3. Make a GA4 event tag. Set the configuration tag from step 1 there as a configuration reference.
4. Publish your GTM container to the production environment.

Done! Now every time you push the `MyTest1` event, you should see a network request to Google's "collect" endpoint with essential generic data about the page.

You can do more, of course, like configuring Enhanced Ecommerce events or sending custom dimensions. You can see that in the link I posted above. Google tries to cover all use cases with their documentation.