# Unable to send custom variable/value/event to GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I want to submit an extra variable to GA4 upon page load.  But I don't see my variable anywhere in Google Analytics and I don't see it mentioned in the `Google Chrome>Developer Tools>Network>Post Request to https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect`.

This is the web page I created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-YOURIDHERE"></script>
<script>
  const gid = 'G-YOURIDHERE';
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag("event", "athlete_type", {
    "event_category": "hockey",
    "event_label": "hockey",
    "value": "hockey"
  });
  gtag('config', gid );
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Replace `G-YOURIDHERE` with your own google analytics ID.  My goal is to use Google Analytics to keep track of each `athlete_type` and when they visited my website.  Simply put, I want to use Google Analytics as a time-based key-value store. You can see that I tried using fields like `event_category, event_label, value` but none of those are being transmitted by my webpage to Google Analytics.

However things like `gtag('config', gid, {page_path: 'anything-i-want'});` does properly send. I can see `anything-i-want` under `Real Time Reports>Event Count by Event Name>page_view>page_path>anything-i-want`. So I know my google analytics account is functional.

What am I doing wrong? How do I send a custom variable to GA4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be checked, if it works, when this line of code:

```
gtag("event", "athlete_type", {
  "event_category": "hockey",
  "event_label": "hockey",
  "value": "hockey"
});
```

is used after this line of code:

```
gtag('config', gid );.
```

The updated code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-YOURIDHERE"></script>
<script>
  const gid = 'G-YOURIDHERE';
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', gid );
  gtag("event", "athlete_type", {
    "event_category": "hockey",
    "event_label": "hockey",
    "value": "hockey"
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked!!!   How come the order matters? Is there a particular google documentation you can suggest I read to understand this?

Comment: Regarding documentation about Google Analytics 4 event setup, using gtag.js API, this link can be checked: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events?client_type=gtag&sjid=7051725448872740779-AP.